# JPA - List annotated with @OrderBy does not order items

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_class")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_gen", sequenceName = "some_class_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
data class SomeClass(

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "someClass", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("date")    
    var items: List<SomeItem>,
) : AbstractEntity()

@Entity
@Table(name = "some_item")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_gen", sequenceName = "some_item_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
data class SomeItem(
    val date: LocalDate,

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    val someClass: SomeClass
) : AbstractEntity()
```

`AbstractEntity` contains trivial things such as id, createdAt etc.

I would expect items to be a sorted list, but it's not, it always contains items in the order in which I've created them.

EDIT: this question is kind of a duplicate of "JPA: can't make OrderBy work". The answer to that question pointed me in the right direction.
To make my tests pass, I need to call the following function before accessing the repository:

```
private fun clearEntityManagerCache() {
    entityManager.flush()
    entityManager.clear()
    entityManager.entityManagerFactory.cache.evictAll()
}
```

After having `entityManager` injected:

```
@Inject
private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager
```

Comment: Did you try to put the direction in sort? `@OrderBy(value = "date asc")`? The default is ASC, but give a shot

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan Tried, does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can get out of the standard JPA `@javax.persistence.OrderBy`, try one of the Hibernate sorting options, either `@org.hibernate.annotations.Sort` or `@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy`.

Adding a SQL fragment into your domain class isn't necessarily the most elegant thing in the world, but it might be the most pragmatic thing.

---

#### Reference:

- https://dzone.com/articles/sorting-collections-hibernate
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/order-by-annotation.html

Comment: but SomeItem is not a basic type or @Embeddable

Comment: @andrew You're right, I made other suggestion... I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it by clearing the entityManager cache, see edited question